# How to change the resolution of screen recording on macOS (i.e. before recording)?

Tags: video, resolution, quicktime, screen-recording

Pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to start a new screen recording brings up a little menu, which has some QuickTime options. But I can't spot any way to reduce the resolution of the recording.

I know a way to reduce the resolution *after* the recording, that is, plonk the video in iMovie, click export, and select a lower resolution. But I would like to find a way to avoid this extra step, by simply recording at a lower resolution (e.g. 540p, 720p, or 1080p etc) to begin with.

Is there a way to screen record in a lower resolution on macOS?

Comment: You might want to experiment by lowering the resolution of the screen you are capturing in System Preferences > Displays to create a smaller file sizes. This seems to be the only way to do this.

Comment: If you save it directly into QuickTime Player, then you can export it to whatever res you want. It records whatever resolution the screen is using, so as @IconDaemon suggests, the only way is to change the screen res.

Comment: I came here for options before making the recording. It seems that there are no options with the macos screen recorder. To edit the movie after I like your iMovie suggestion. I then tried VLC and I got more video codec and framerate options, and the output is more optimal for my needs.